# C# smart cards serial intrface

Tags: c#, serial-port, smartcard

Have a trouble with smart card reader. Reader is connect to pc through Usb-to-Serial converter. Can't read anything from reader.

```
...
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[256];
        byte[] recived = new byte[256];
        data[0] = 0x00;
        data[1] = 0xA4;
        data[2] = 0x04;
        data[3] = 0x00;
        data[4] = 0x00;
        data[5] = 0x00;
        data[6] = 0x00;
        System.IO.Ports.SerialPort sp = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM4", 38400, System.IO.Ports.Parity.None, 8, System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One);
        sp.WriteTimeout = 300;
        sp.ReadTimeout = 300;
        sp.DataReceived += Sp_DataReceived;
        sp.ErrorReceived += Sp_ErrorReceived;
        if (sp.IsOpen)
        {sp.Close();}
        sp.Open();
        try {
            sp.Write(data, 0, 7);
            int bt = sp.ReceivedBytesThreshold;
            sp.Read(recived, 0, bt);
            if (bt != 0)
            {   Console.WriteLine(bt.ToString());
                Console.ReadKey();}
        } catch (Exception ex){
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();}    
    }
    private static void Sp_ErrorReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
    {Console.ReadKey();}
    private static void Sp_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {Console.ReadKey();}
}
```

}

Code doesn't do anything as if there isn't card reader in the system.

Comment: Imagine you were one of us. Would you be able to offer support for this question? Which information would you be missing?

Comment: `sp.DataReceived += Sp_PinChanged` does not seem to be well defined. Sorry, but code should at least compile, -1 for that.

Comment: First in device manager serial ports check if your smar card reader is detected by your computer. Are you sure it's in port com4? Are there any exceptions? what happens after executing the code on sp.Write???

Comment: Sorry fellas, i know that the question is unadequate, but i have trouble with this device and can't find answer for a week.

Comment: First of all - my device is in port4, there aren't any exception and code do nothing - only blank screen. There is not card reader in  the system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you're attaching the event handlers *after* you send something to the reader. That's not good. I recommend initializing the `SerialPort` instance completely (set it up, attach events, etc) and *only after that*, open the connection and communicate.

Also your application doesn't *wait* for anything. If you use the asynchronous communication (by defining the `DataReceived` event) you need to make sure your application actually *loops and waits*.

Your console application doesn't do that. It writes something to the serial port and then quits as it steps out of the `Main` method. If you expect an answer you need to decide:

1. Use the synchronous way calling the methods to actually *block/read* from the serial port.
2. Use the asynchronous way as you started doing, but then make your application run without blocking any threads.

And please: Don't mix the two! I see a lot of code where people in `DataReceived` write a loop because they don't get all the information in one go. Don't do that. Instead build a buffer and check it for complete transmissions. No `Read` in `DataReceived`!

---

The following code might work. It will not implement the asynchronous variant, but the blocking, synchronous approach:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[256];
    byte[] recived = new byte[256];
    data[0] = 0x00;
    data[1] = 0xA4;
    data[2] = 0x04;
    data[3] = 0x00;
    data[4] = 0x00;
    data[5] = 0x00;
    data[6] = 0x00;

    using (System.IO.Ports.SerialPort sp = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM4", 38400, System.IO.Ports.Parity.None, 8, System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One))
    {
        try 
        {
            sp.Open();

            sp.Write(data, 0, 7);

            int bytesRead = sp.Read(recived, 0, received.Length);
            if (bytesRead != 0)
            {
                string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received, 0, bytesRead);
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        } 
    }   
}
```

If *that* doesn't show any result on the console, then there might be several causes of error, including:

1. Wrong COM configuration (is BAUD rate, etc. correct?)
2. Wrong serial port (do you have more than one?)
3. Device doesn't communicate the way you think (are you sending the correct command?)
4. etc..

Comment: Thank you for answer. I fixed my code. But it also does nothing. Programm doesn't go through the DataRecived. When i set read/write timeout(or thread sleep) only "waiting time is out" on the screen.

Comment: Well, if you "fixed" your code, please change your question to reflect the new version. I can not tell anything if I can't see the code.

Comment: I corrected my code. Sorry for my english i not good in it(as and in C#).

Comment: Your code will not work properly. I'm going to change my answer to show you how it *might* work.

Comment: Thank you, as usual is blank screen. I was trying different configuration of COM, also different config of serial port(only one) and many different command(according ISO). Unfortunately i have no description of this device only small pice of paper with main characteristic.

Comment: Well, maybe you better use something like PuTTY to test the device before you start implementing an application. That reduces the point of error to one, not two (if you implement your own application you'll never know whether it's your application that fails or the device).

Comment: I did so without a result.

Comment: Well. All I can say is: Test your communication with PuTTY and if you know how it works, write your application. Sometimes it also helps to Google for the product to find manuals or at least other developers running into the same problems.